# Cannot get id of current user when reloading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to connect to my API, i did like that:

```
   mounted(){
        http.get(sharedUrl.EXPERIENCE+ this.currentUser.id ).then(response => {
           //do some staff
        });
    }, 
    computed: {
        currentUser() {
            return this.$store.getters.currentUser
        }
    }
```

All it's right. I get the right response; but when reloading the page, i didn't get the API response. ( CurrentUser id is null).

How can i fix it please ?

Comment: Can you share you store code? Are you getting the API response when reloading? Do you have a persistant store?

Comment: This is hard to answer without more context. Does the `mounted` callback happen again on page reload? Are you looking for a solution that doesn't require the API call after a reload?

Comment: When you refresh the page it is as if the component is destroyed, to fix this you must save the data to local storage